# Right Navigation bar margins

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a Navbar in bootstrap that contains a full height a tag but I cannot get it to work.

```css
#su
{
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #ea3ace;
    color: snow;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#" id="su">test</a></li>
</ul>
```

But in the website, it shows up like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0Xei.jpg

As you can see, there are margins on the top and right of the nav. I can't get it to work no matter what and would really appreciate if you guys could help me a bit.

Comment: You need to remove any padding associated with the parent nodes of the `a` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply overwrite Bootstraps styles, e.g. `margin-right: 0;` on the `navbar-right` class with using a higher specificity for the selectors.

```css
.nav.navbar-right {
  margin-right: 0;
}
#su {
  padding: 20px 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #ea3ace;
  color: snow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li>
    <a href="#" id="su">test</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```